# Why Kafka Streams reset offsets to zero after Kafka Server upgrade 2.4?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

### Problem Description:

I have a kafka topic with 12 partitions which consumer application is polling from. After the Kafka broker upgrade to 2.4 from version 2.2.1, I noticed that the consumer application lag turns to a higher number and reprocessing the records again from offset zero.

### Topic configuration:

```
cleanup.policy=compact
delete.retention.ms=100
segment.ms=100
min.cleanable.dirty.ratio=0.01
```

### Streaming app libraries:

```
kafka-streams (version 2.0.1)
spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams (version 2.1.2.RELEASE)
Spring-kafka (version 2.2.6.RELEASE)
```

### Application Logs:

```
[Consumer clientId=web-streaming-application-8023d9d2-e761-41c5-9b90-d586a3bbe095-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=web-consumer-application] Resetting offset for partition web-streaming-application_employees-4 to offset 0.
[Consumer clientId=web-streaming-application-8023d9d2-e761-41c5-9b90-d586a3bbe095-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=web-streaming-application] Fetch offset 3378632 is out of range for partition web-streaming-application_employees-4, resetting offset
```

The Kafka brokers logs and metrics seems to be fine and no replication issues are there. I don't have an evidence that the upgrade is causing a problem. So I'm seeking your help to understand what is going on.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

### Application Config:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: web-streaming-application
  kafka:
    properties:
      security.protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
      sasl.mechanism: GSSAPI
      sasl.kerberos.service.name: kafka
      bootstrap.servers: ${kafka.bootstrap-servers}
      value.serializer: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonSerializer
  cloud.stream:
    kafka.streams:
      binder:
        brokers: ${kafka.bootstrap-servers}
        configuration:
          security.protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
          sasl.mechanism: GSSAPI
          sasl.kerberos.service.name: kafka
          default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
        serdeError: logAndContinue
      bindings:
        employeeInput:
          consumer:
            value-serde: business.serde.EmployeeJsonSerde
            application.id: ${spring.application.name}
    bindings:
      employeeInput:
        destination: ${kafka.topics.employee}
        group: ${spring.application.name}
```

Comment: Not sure why it's happening. Somehow, Kafka thinks that your consumer is a new one and tries to consume from the earliest offset available. From a Spring Cloud Stream standpoint, it doesn't directly try to reset any offsets and hands things off to Kafka Streams.

Comment: Thanks soby for your input. I found this [Bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9543) in Kafka server 2.4 so I have made a rollback to the version 2.2.1.

Comment: As a general rule confluent recommends upgrading only to non x.0 version, since they are usually very buggy, and instead wait to x.1